# Docker multiple environments

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, development-environment

I'm trying to wrap my head around Docker, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out. I tried to implement it in my small project (MERN stack), and I was thinking how do you distinct between development, (maybe staging), and production environments.

I saw one [example](https://github.com/Hashnode/mern-starter) where they used 2 Docker files, and 2 docker-compose files, (each pair for one env, so Dockerfile + docker-compose.yml for prod, Dockerfile-dev + docker-compose-dev.yml for dev).

But this just seems like a bit of an overkill for me. I would prefer to have it only in two files.

Also one of the problem is that e.g. for development I want to install nodemon globally, but not for poduction.

In perfect solution I imagine running something like that

```
docker-compose -e ENV=dev build
docker-compose -e ENV=dev up
```

Keep in mind, that I still don't fully get docker, so if you caught some of mine misconceptions about docker, you can point them out.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could take some clues from "[Using Compose in production](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/)"

> You’ll almost certainly want to make changes to your app configuration that are more appropriate to a live environment. These changes may include:
>
> - Removing any volume bindings for application code, so that code stays inside the container and can’t be changed from outside
> - Binding to different ports on the host
> - Setting environment variables differently (e.g., to decrease the verbosity of logging, or to enable email sending)
> - Specifying a restart policy (e.g., restart: always) to avoid downtime
> - Adding extra services (e.g., a log aggregator)

The advice is then not quite similar to the example you mention:

> For this reason, you’ll probably want to define an additional Compose file, say `production.yml`, which specifies production-appropriate configuration. This configuration file only needs to include the changes you’d like to make from the original Compose file.
>
> ```
> docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f production.yml up -d
> ```

This **[overriding mechanism](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#different-environments)** is better than trying to mix dev and prod logic in one compose file, with environment variable to try and select one.

Note: If you name your second dockerfile `docker-compose.override.yml`, a simple `docker-compose up` would read the overrides automatically.
But in your case, a name based on the environment is clearer.

Answer (score 11):

Docker Compose will read `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` by default. [Understanding-Multiple-Compose-Files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files)

You can set a default `docker-compose.yml` and different overwrite compose file. For example, `docker-compose.prod.yml` `docker-compose.test.yml`. Keep them in the same place.

Then create a symbolic link named `docker-compose.override.yml` for each env.
Track `docker-compose.{env}.yml` files and add `docker-compose.override.yml` to `.gitignore`.
In prod env: `ln -s ./docker-compose.prod.yml ./docker-compose.override.yml`
In test env: `ln -s ./docker-compose.test.yml ./docker-compose.override.yml`
The project structure will then look like this:

```
project\
  - docker-compose.yml       # tracked
  - docker-compose.prod.yml  # tracked
  - docker-compose.test.yml  # tracked
  - docker-compose.override.yml # ignored & linked to override composefile for current env 
  - src/
  - ...
```

Then you have done. In each environment, you can use the compose-file with the same command `docker-compose up`

If you are not sure, use `docker-compose config` to check if it's been override properly.